# Does SymmetricDS support CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb, symmetricds

Wondering whether anyone has used  or knows whether "SymmetricDS" (DB replication) supports "CouchDB"?

I have looked on the SymmetricDS site's FAQ and don't see CouchDB explicitly listed as being supported.  I also see someone asking SymmetricDS 3 years ago in 2013 to add support for CouchDB.  Wondering whether anyone knows if that support has been added in the last 3 years?

Comment: there's no support for couchDb, but nothing stops you from introducing it and submitting a pull request

Answer (score 0):

SymmetricDS does not currently support CouchDB but does support other noSQL databases like Mongo. Adding a new dialect can usually be done in under 40 hours. Generally dialects are built with sponsorship to move the process along faster than 40 hours.